# Get a value even if the person gender is not available in wiki data sparql query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

This is a simple SPARQL query that gives the person gender. Now what I wanted to know that if the person gender is not given, can we get a value 0 or something like 'yes' or 'no' instead of an empty cell. The reason I want to do this is that I have some QID's in which some have gender and some don't. When I implement it in Python the query doesn't give result for all.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?genderLabel ?person ?personLabel
WHERE {
# set ?item to Person
BIND(wd:Q11831 AS ?person)

OPTIONAL { ?person  wdt:P21 ?gender. }

# set language for labels
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

Comment: Either use `if else` or `coalesce`, for example:  `select ?person ?gender ?gender2 ?gender3
WHERE {

BIND(wd:Q11831 AS ?person)

optional{
?person  wdt:P21 ?gender.}
BIND(if(bound(?gender), 1, 0) as ?gender2)
  BIND(coalesce(?gender, "no") as ?gender3)


SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}`

Comment: @UninformedUser you seem quite informed.... why don’t you post answers as such? That would, among other things, allow people to see that the q has been answered.